# OpenID + Google returning different unique ids for same user

Tags: java, openid

I am working on a project using openid as a login. So far its been working fine. Today however I noticed a user using gmail provider could not log in with their existing account.

I looked over the code and could find no issue. In the end I made a copy of their existing unique id key and made them create a new account. When the new account was created I compared the two openid unique keys and they were different for the same account.

As far as I know this would break the whole premise of openid.

I would like to know if others have had a similar experience and so I can identify if the issue is related to openid / gmail or is something on my end.

Project Specs.
- Java 6.0
- Tomcat 7.0
- MySQL 5.5
- JOpenID 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Google will create a different OpenID for each URL [as better described by Andrew Arnott](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/) here.**

Do notice that Google ID, Facebook ID, Flickr ID for a same user coming from any one of those different sites... will be unique!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense since i recently changed some server stuff around resulting in a different domain.

Comment: @user845729 great! Now, in Stack Overflow style (SO) you should accept the answer if you think it helped you. That way you'll improve my reputation and you'll also get some points for yourself. You probably should spend 3 minutes reading the FAQ to familiarize yourself with the community. http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Welcome to SO.